# Providing layer content via quartz2D drawings in xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, xcode6

Hi according to [the core animation programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/SettingUpLayerObjects/SettingUpLayerObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH13-SW12) you can provide a layers content by calling a custom layer class and manually writing a display method where the you provide the content. I want to use a quartz2D drawing for the content (written in a separate custom class that uses quartz) but I do not know how.

I am trying to use the display method here

```
-(void) displayLayer: (CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGColorSpaceRef)ctc  inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {}
```

the method for the quartz2D drawing

```css
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
        
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
        
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
        
        CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(60,170,200,80);
        
        CGContextAddRect(context, rectangle);
        
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You got the method signature all mixed up. Instead of:

`-(void) displayLayer: (CALayer *)layer
    inContext:(CGColorSpaceRef)ctc  inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {}`

You should use:

`- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx`

Let me know if this was the actual problem. I'm happy to provide a working example.

Comment: The issue was that my custom layer would not display in the view and therefore I could not animate it, I fixed it by changing the subclass of the layer to CALayer and assign the UIView in the view controller to it. Although now I am dealing with a "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)" error, where the app crashes at launch.